# Find the remainder of this division with generator 10011

Tags: math, binary, generator, division

I am trying to find the value R (remainder) when the generator G is 10011, and the `value D` (dividend) to be 0101101010.
I rewrite the dividend (D) to 0101101010 0000 since `r = 4` if using CRC. The divider is 10011. When I set up the division, the first digit of the result (not the remainder) is 1, however, after the first subtraction from `1*10011`, I'll get `11000`, which is still a five digit binary. How am I supposed to do from this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure but I think you are subtracting from the wrong position, you need to align the first 1's of `D` and `G`, like so:

```
01011010100000
 10011
00010110100000
   10011
00000101100000
     10011
00000001010000
       10011
00000000011100
         10011
00000000001111

R=1111
```